# How do I replace the values of a specific timeframe with a weighting of the same timeframe from previous years?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has data for 4 years which kind of look like this:

| Year | Week | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 1 | 25 |
| 2018 | 2 | 28 |
| 2018 | 3 | 26 |
| 2019 | 1 | 24 |
| 2019 | 2 | 34 |
| 2019 | 3 | 30 |
| 2020 | 1 | 27 |
| 2020 | 2 | 33 |
| 2020 | 3 | 32 |
| 2021 | 1 | 39 |
| 2021 | 2 | 43 |
| 2021 | 3 | 41 |

What I want to do is to replace the values in 2021 with a weighting of the previous 3 years values in the same time frame. So in this example replace only the values from weeks 1 to 3 in 2021 (there could be other weeks to be left alone) with say: 45%*2020 + 30%*2019 + 25%*2018

Which would give us the following for 2021:

| Year | Week | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 20.65 |
| 2021 | 2 | 32.05 |
| 2021 | 3 | 29.9 |

And we got the values for 2021 week 3 by doing:
0.45*32 + 0.3*30 + 0.25*26 = 14.4 + 9 + 6.5 = 29.9

Also, I want to be able to skip years if I want to, 2021 can be based off of 2020, 2019, and 2016 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom function as it sounds like you need customizable parameters. There isn't a specific pandas method that can do this:

```
def f(df=df, years=[], weeks=[], weights=[], current_year=2021):
    df = df[df['Week'].isin(weeks)]
    series_weights = df['Year'].map({year : weight for year, weight in zip(years, weights)})
    df['Value'] = df['Value'] * series_weights
    df = df.assign(Year=current_year).groupby(['Year', 'Week'], as_index=False)['Value'].sum()
    return df


f(years=[2018,2019,2020], weeks=[1,2,3], weights=[0.25,0.3,0.45])

Out[1]: 
   Year  Week  Value
0  2021     1  25.60
1  2021     2  32.05
2  2021     3  29.90
```